# Excel VB Macro to populate cells based on a value entered

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a macro/VB to populate cells to the left and right of a particular cell I am entering data into.

So, let's say I have three columns. The center column will be where I type a number of 30 or 31. If I type 30, I want the cells on the left to populate with PENDING and the cell on the right to populate with TBD. Similar function if I type 31 but will be different data.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: Look at Worksheet change event which may give you what you seek.

Comment: Why not use a formula? for example in column A you could use `=If(B1=30, "PENDING","SomethingElse")` and in C column `=If(B1=30, "TBD", "SomethingElse")`, this will make your worksheet run much faster, and it will save you from all the errors you will get when deleting, and changing many cells at once, and if you enter 30 or 31 in another cell in the worksheet it won't change information you didn't want to, while all this can be handled with VBA its pointless as it will still be slower then just using a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Value = 30 And Target.Column > 1 Then
    Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = "PENDING"
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = "TBD"
ElseIf Target.Value = 31 Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "SOME OTHER DATA"
End If
End Sub
```